# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$ and define $H$ on $[a,b]$ by $H(x)=\int^b_xf.$ Find $H'(x)$.

I started by using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus since this is the chapter that it comes from in the book I have. Now I'm either doing something right or horribly wrong. Any corrections or information you have on this question would be appreciated. Below is what I have attempted as of now.

Now since $f$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, we know that $H(x)$ is differentiable on the interval by the FTC. Also if $f$ is continuous at a point $c \in [a,b]$, then F is differentiable at $c$ and $F'(c)=f(c)$. So based on the information given we know that $H'(x)$ does exist.

So I then used the fact that $\int^b_af(x)=F(b)-F(a)$ and I get that $H(x)=\int^b_xf(x)=H(b)-H(x)$. I used H in this case because the book stated, If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and G is any antiderivative of $f$, then $\int^b_af=G(b)-G(a)$, so I figured that this was the correct way to interpret this question.

From here do I really just take the derivative of $H$?

I did and got $H'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int^b_xf=\frac{d}{dx}[H(b)-H(x)]$. Is this completed or incorrect, I don't see where to go from here.

Comment: I think you're confuse using $H$ for two different things. If you write $F=\int_a^x f(t)dt$, then $H(x)=F(b)-F(x)$, but NOT $H(x)=H(b) - H(x)$ (otherwise you would have $H(x)=\frac{H(b)}{2}=$constant ...) from there you can use the fundamental theorem on $F$, noticing that $F(b)$ is constant w.r.t $x$ so its derivative is null, and get $H'(c) = -F'(c) = -f(c)$

Comment: Thanks I was thinking the same thing $-f(c)$. Is there a big difference between the $-f(c)$ or $-f(x)$ in this case? One is stating that at a specific point this is what it equals and the other overall for all x that is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are supposed to write down $$\frac{H(x)-H(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ and to prove that the limit as $x \to x_0$ exists and is finite. It is not really difficult, you need to use the additivity of the integral with respect to the domain and the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$. You can find a proof in Rudin's book *Principles of mathematical analysis*, if you don't succeed.

**Edit:** I'll clarify my suggestion. There are two ways of solving this exercise. The first one goes as follows: let $F$ be a primitive of $f$ (on $[a,b]$), and notice that $H(x)=F(b)-F(x)$. Hence $H'(x)=0-F'(x)=-f(x)$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. In this case, the exercise is really, really trivial.

The second way assumes that you are supposed to *prove* that $H$ is differentiable according to the definition:
$$
H'(x)=\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{H(x)-H(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\int_x^b f - \int_{x_0}^b f}{x-x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\int_x^{x_0}f}{x-x_0}.
$$
Now you have to evaluate this limit. Actually, this *is* the proof of the fact that $-H$ is a primitive of $f$.

Comment: I'm not following what you are saying. I get putting the equation into lim notation like you mentioned above. But I'm not following the additivity part? or the continuity of f since it already states that f is a continuous real valued function. I did look in Rudin's book but did not find what you were referring too. Do you have a page or chapter specifically in mind? Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: I think he suggests you to prove the fundamental theorem yourself, but acutally you can use it as it is, right ?

Comment: Yes I am in the FTC section of my Real Analysis, so I can use it as is without having to prove the thm's that came in previous chapters. Thanks